# Flutter: search bar-send request to server after delay

Tags: rest, search, flutter, searchbar

I have a search bar which does a rest call after 1 second that the user has typed something. But, in case the user digits more letters, like "asd", actually it will perform 3 requests, one for "a", one for "s" and one for "d". Is there a way to do only one call when the user stops?

The code is:

```
appBarTitle = new TextField(
    controller: _filterController,
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Search...'
    )
);
_filterController.addListener(() {
  if (_filterController.text.isEmpty) {
  } else {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      userWrites(_filterController.text);
    });
  }
});

userWrites(String filterName){
  try {
//TODO: call
  }catch(_) {
 }   

}
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't tested yet. I'm doing more important stuff right now. I'll let you know as soon as I have time.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if it's still useful, but I solved it using the Timer class.

```
Timer timer;
appBarTitle = new TextField(
    controller: _filterController,
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Search...'
    )
);
_filterController.addListener(() {
  if (_filterController.text.isEmpty) {
  } else {
    if(timer != null){
      timer.cancel();
      timer = null;    
    }
    timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), userWrites);
  }
});

userWrites(){
  try {
    print(_filterController.text);
    //TODO: call
  }catch(_) {
 }   

}
```